# Trying to open a webpage from shell, but the string breaks

Tags: shell, url

I'm trying to open a series of URLs using the 'open' command in shell.

open http://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/country-statistical-profile-australia-2013-2_5k9d5vhlgxkf.xls;jsessionid=lzfo8lhxtes0.x-oecd-live-02?contentType=/ns/KeyTable,/ns/StatisticalPublication&itemId=/content/table/20752288-table-aus&containerItemId=/content/table/20752288-table-aus&accessItemIds=&mimeType=application/vnd.ms-excel

The problem is, after the '.xls; bit in the URL, I think the shell thinks that's the end of the URL, and tries to open the page, and opens the wrong one. That's my guess, because when I type 'echo ' I get:

```
[9] 4813
[10] 4814
[11] 4815
[12] 4816
[7]   Done                    containerItemId=/content/table/20752288-table-aus
[8]   Done                    accessItemIds=
[9]   Done                    jsessionid=lzfo8lhxtes0.x-oecd-live-02?contentType=/ns/KeyTable,/ns/StatisticalPublication
[10]   Done                    itemId=/content/table/20752288-table-aus
```

Is there a way to, like, make sure the entire string is used?

Comment: Semicolon is a delimiter. You need to escape it or put the whole string between `"`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't know it was a delimiter in shell. Works now. (If you add this as an answer I'll accept it if you want)

Comment: I added it as an answer with some examples. By the way, nice art on your page!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what shell you are using, but the semicolon is often used to separate multiple commands given on the same line.

You can either escape the semicolon with backslash or put the whole string between double quotes `"`.

**Examples:**

This will execute two different echos, one with `string1` and the other with `string2`.

```
echo string1; echo string2
```

This will execute one echo as `string1; echo string2` since the semicolon is escaped with backslash.

```
echo string1\; echo string2
```

This will also execute one echo as `string1; echo string2` since the whole string is between double quotes:

```
echo "string1; echo string2"
```